# IE11 Automation: Change value of drop down list

Tags: vba, excel

I have included the code I use to navigate to a particular website; the end game here is to try and click the drop down list under "Login to" and select an option and click go. This is a learning experience for me. I would love to know the WHY? behind the code.

```
Sub internetautomation2()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer      'Created Class of type InternetExplorer
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer   'Initiated Class, object IE created
                                    'Properties and methods of
                                    'Internet Explorer now usable

    IE.Top = 0                      'IE window properties Topleft corner  
    IE.width = 1500                 '1500pixels wide

    IE.Visible = True               

    IE.Navigate ("ibc.com")         'Navigate to particular website

    While IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_LOADING    'Wait for website to load
        DoEvents
    Wend

   'Clicking drop down list,selecting option,click go

   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what this question has to do with JavaScript, but just wire up a change event handler to your list and navigate to the list value:

```
 Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
   IE.Navigate (ComboBox1.Value)
 End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but I am a complete novice and do not understand what you mean. Are you trying to tell me to navigate to the url that would be produced by selecting something in the drop down menu?

Comment: Are you asking how to make the navigation after selecting a list item work? If so, in Excel's Design View, double-click on your drop down list. This will cause you to be brought into the code editor and a new sub-routine will have been created for the Change event of the list. Just add the IE.Navigate code I show above into that sub-routine, but change my code from ComboBox1 to the name of your list.

Comment: Im not sure we are talking about the same thing. I am trying to click on a drop down list on the "ibc.com" website using VBA.

Comment: Unless ibc.com exposes a public API, you can't do what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
'Set to the secod option "Deposit express"
IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_IBCOtherOnlineServices_ddlLoginTo").selectedIndex = 1
'click the submit button
IE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_IBCOtherOnlineServices_btnLoginTo").Click
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tim. The code didn't work for me. I entered it as you provided, but i get an aumation error.....Run time error ,automation error, unspecified error. I am using ie11, don't know if that's the problem. Vba debugs to the first statement

Comment: I get an object not set error. Do you mind showing me the full code. I have a feeling I might not be doing something simple.